Do all languages distinguish between persons and non-persons?
I am teaching the concept of "person" and "personhood" to my Grade 12 philosophy class, and we have a video to watch in which the philosopher observes that English pronouns distinguish persons (he, she, who) from non-persons (it, which). Do all or most languages make a similar distinction? French, for example, I know has no "it" pronoun; in French, even non-persons are assigned a gender. But it is possible that French distinguishes between persons and non-persons in some other way.
Thanks!

I’m pretty sure that all languages distinguish persons and non-persons in some way – if nothing else, by having a word that means ‘person’ or ‘human being’, which represents a semantic category whose items are distinct from everything else precisely by virtue of being persons. A language which is unable to distinguish people from inanimate objects would fall at quite an early hurdle of communication. Whether all languages have grammatical or morphological ways to make this distinction (e.g., with pronouns, inflection, animacy markers, distinct roots, etc.) is a different matter.

Intersting related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/38157/9781I

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The relevant linguistic concept is animacy, but what is considered animate or inanimate can vary significantly across the languages of the world. Besides humans, animals, gods, some objects in nature like trees or rivers, and other things can be animate. Animacy is related to Grammatical gender. There are many languages without grammatical gender, more than half (145 of 257) of the languages in the WALS sample, but some of these language may show other traces of animacy, as in the Japanese example in the Wikipedia article quoted above. I don't know if there are languages not encoding animacy at all, WALS does not say anything about it.

And sometimes, the animacy distinction is applied to only a subset of the available grammatical genders. E.g., the masculine animate and inanimate in Slavic languages when analysed as a subgender, as not very explicitly hinted by the linked Wikipedia. Perhaps there are examples in other genders in some languages like those женщина and животное but I did not really get what the author means there.

@VladimirFГероямслава One can discuss if some Slavic languages have a four gender system with masculine animated, masculine iinanimated, feminine, and neuter as values. In fact, mostly classical tradition hinders us from taking this point of view.

Romance languages like Italian have grammatical gender, but do not distinguish animacy as far as I can tell (the gender is masculine/feminine and objects get slotted in one of the two more or less arbitrarily). I cannot think of a way of marking animacy in Italian - certainly marking the gender does not do so.

@DenisNardin - In Romanian, all neuters are inanimate, collective or abstract entities. No animal or plant is neuter (excepting the word "animal" itself, which can be considered abstract, and a farfetched unused and unusable recent entry "macrouri", plural of "macrou"=mackerel, which should be uncountable.) Some inanimate are feminine but few are masculine. Neuter has a specific plural ending -uri which appears with the plural feminine only with mass/collective/uncountable entities (of the meaning similar to English silver/silverware - for example brass/brassware=alamă/alămuri).

@cipricus I suspected Romanian might have been different - that's why I added "like Italian" :). But in Italian or French the neuter simply does not exist and the gender distinction is not related to animacy. Inanimate objects can be arbitrarily masculine or feminine, and sometimes they have forms of both gender (e.g. tavolo vs tavola, both of which mean "table")

@DenisNardin - On the vanished neuter in Italian see this.

@cipricus I don't quite understand those messages - I suspect they might referring to the names changing gender between singular and plural. This is, of course, a residual of Latin neuter but it is not perceived as a neuter synchronically. Either way, this has nothing to do with animacy...

I would question the claim that animacy is "the" relevant linguistic concept (i.e. the only one). In English, for example, the distinction between "he/she" and "it" sometimes hinges on personhood and not on animacy, as when a dog is referred to as "it" even though its animacy is not in doubt (and even when its gender is known). Of course there are others factors that can influence the use of "it" in English, but my point is just that the linguistic concept of animacy is not one-to-one with that of personhood.

The Natural Semantic Metalanguage is a framework and research project which attempts to identify the basic semantic building blocks of human language, which they call "semantic primes." These words (sometimes affixes or phrases) are the base level semantic concepts on which everything else is built, and are argued to be present in every natural language. Over many decades the list of primes as been refined based on empirical evidence in dozens of languages.
Some of the semantic primes that have been identified are SOMEONE and SOMETHING (as well as PEOPLE). Without strong evidence to the contrary we can expect all natural human languages to distinguish between "someones" and "somethings", ie, between persons and non-persons.
Gender and case are language specific. Each language only grammaticalises some grammatical categories and leaves others ungrammaticalised. A language may only have two genders (which may be called "masculine" and "feminine") but that doesn't in the slightest imply that the language doesn't recognise the existence of things that aren't persons. What it does mean is that the language puts everything into two boxes. Those boxes are named because of how they group people, but the labels don't define everything in their boxes.

The linguistic term is ‘animacy’. It’s very important to understand though that animacy is not a purely linguistic thing. Culture, and especially religion, has a huge impact as well, and that shapes the language to some extent.
The Ojibwe language is probably the best example I can think of of this. Ojibwe has no grammatical gender, but instead distinguishes animate and inanimate nouns via noun class (think like binary grammatical gender, but classifying animacy instead). But that distinction is heavily tied to whether Ojibwe culture recognizes the referent of the noun as possessing a ‘spirit’ or not, which means that many things that are spiritually very important to the Ojibwe people are animate nouns, even if they are not living things.
It’s also important to understand though that animacy is both a semantic property (that is, a function of the meaning of a word in context) and a grammatical property (that is, something explicitly marked as part of the morphology of a word or the syntax surrounding its usage).
The way a language marks animacy in its<--was:it's--> grammar varies greatly:

Basque, like Ojibwe, has no grammatical gender, but marks animacy as a binary noun class (every noun is grammatically either animate or inanimate).
Georgian primarily uses verb choice to mark animacy of the associated nouns.
Navajo marks relative animacy of nouns in a clause by descending word order (the first noun is the most animate, the last is the least animate, a prefix on the verb marks which one is the subject) and has a relatively clear ranking of animacy (adult humans (and lightning interestingly enough) at the top, followed by young/infant humans and large animals, medium animals, small animals, natural forces, and then abstractions at the bottom)
English marks animacy through choice of third-person pronouns, and also to a lesser extent by syntax of possessives (possessives formed using the preposition ‘of’ are less likely to have an animate referent in English).
A number of Slavic languages mark animacy only on masculine nouns.
Spanish marks animacy of concrete direct objects with the preposition a, and sometimes marks animacy with the choice and presence of pronouns (if a pronoun that could be omitted in Spanish is included, it’s referent is almost always animate).
Finnish only marks animacy with choice of pronouns.
I believe Turkish does not mark animacy grammatically.
Japanese largely does not mark animacy, except for the use of the verbs iru and aru (iru is only used with animate nouns, aru is only used with inanimate nouns), unless you also want to count explicit personification of inanimate objects (which is enough to be considered common in Japanese culture).
Tamil marks rationality instead of animacy, based on historical culturally perceived capacity for rational thought. Inanimate objects are always irrational, but many animate objects (such as children or animals) are too (which leads to interesting secondary effects such as children not having gender from a grammatical perspective).
Dyirbal (an Australian Aboriginal language) largely defies ‘simple’ classification. Most animate objects, as well as male humans, are in one noun class. Women, water, fire, violence, and a handful of specific (mostly dangerous) animals are in a second noun class. Edible fruits and vegetables are in a third, and then everything else is in a fourth.
Toki Pona (a constructed language) does not mark animacy at all. In theory it’s trivially possible to have a constructed language not mark animacy

However, even in those languages that do not mark animacy grammatically, it is still a semantic property of the word. For example, ‘cat’, chat/chatte, gato, kissa, kedi, neko/猫, Pūṉai/பூனை, and soweli, are all semantically animate in their respective languages, irrespective of how those languages mark grammatical animacy. Some languages do not agree on what is semantically animate (see my comments about Ojibwe at the top of the answer for an example), but for a lot of words there is general agreement among languages as to what is animate and what isn’t. As far as I know, there is no language that lacks a semantic distinction of animacy, because it’s a core part of how people conceptualize the world.

There is an interesting discussion of Dyirbal in Lakoff. Bayi, the category that includes Men includes boomerangs and fishing spears, and Balan, the category with women includes shields and fighting spears. Bees, interestingly are in category 4, Bala. I'm glad nobody made me learn Dyirbal as a child.

What about quelqu'un vs.  quelque chose in French? Is it grammatical or purely lexical?

As for Finnish, IIUC personal pronouns (hän/ne) can only be used for humans, while animals and things are referred to with se.

@phipsgabler You’re right, I’m not sure how I forgot that...

@SirCornflakes I’m not certain, French is one of the few Italic languages I have very little knowledge of, though I guess I could have clarified that further in my answer.

See also the comments to the question by Eau qui dort about animacy in French.

@SirCornflakes This comment and the following three.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks.

Not all languages distinguish clearly between persons and non-persons. Some languages do, however, make grammatical distinctions based on animacy, which can be closely related to the distinction between persons and non-persons.
The pronoun system distinguishes between persons (he, she, who) and non-persons (it, which).
In languages like Ojibwe or Navajo, there are distinctions based on "animate" versus "inanimate" categories, which might include not just people but also animals or other entities considered important or "alive" in cultural terms.
